# How to get subdirectories under a folder returning arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
    File file = new File("/WEB-INF/view/skin/outlogin");
    String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return dir.isDirectory();
      }
    });

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
    if(directories!=null)
        for(int i=0; i<directories.length; i++) { list.add(directories[i]); }

    return list;
```

this is a code in a method, and I want to return it as ArrayList method. however, directories is output as an error. is there any problem here?

OR

Is there anyway to print out String array in jsp as model2?

Comment: Show the entire method please... or at least the method declaration.  Also, _"directories is output as an error"_ is rather ambiguous. Please edit your post and include the entire message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `ServeltContext's getRealPath(virtualPath)` method which returns `real` path of given `virtual` path.

```
String virutalPath="/WEB-INF/view/skin/outlogin";
String realPath=getServletContext().getRealPath(virtualPath);
File file = new File(realPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`String[] directories = file.list(.....)`
use the

```
File[] files= file.listFiles(.....)
```

Hope it will resolve your problem.